# rowspan_problem using html in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql, html

```
$count=0;
$avg=0;
$min=0;
$max=0;
$sql1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM activities");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)):
    $act=$row['act'];
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT activity,worker,grams,start_time,end_time,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time,end_time) AS time FROM works WHERE activity='$act'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    $count=$count+2;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=<?php $count;?>><?php echo $row['act']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $avg=0;
        $max=0;
        $min=0;
        while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))):
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
            $result=$row['grams']/($row['time']/60);
            $avg=$avg+$result;
            if($max < $result){
                $max=$result;
            }
            if($min>$result){
            $min=$result;
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['worker']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $avg=$avg/($count-2); ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $avg ;?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $max ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $min ;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Actually I want to export these `html` table to the `excel`
I am using `jQuery` for this goal 
I exported it successfully but `rowspan` is not working at all

Comment: improve code and question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to `echo` the `$count` variable.

```
<td rowspan="<?php echo $count;?>">
```

Comment: its working i forgot to keep thanks for remainding meeeeee

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing one thing.

```
<td rowspan=<?php $count;?>><?php echo $row['act']; ?></td>
```

It should be:

```
<td rowspan='<?php $count;?>'><?php echo $row['act']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
< td rowspan=<?php $count;?>><?php echo $row['act']; ?></td >
```

Should be:

```
< td rowspan='<?= $count ?>'><= echo $row['act']; ?></td >
```